# PAGENATION. Пагинация python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здраствуйте. Делаю парсинг страницы (ajax). Нужно листать страницы. Для перехода след страницу нужно делать шаг `+str(count)+`, где `count=10` в `URL`.

```
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user_agent = ''
URL = 'https://example.com/page='+str(count)+'&start=10' # URL для парсинга

nonce = str(round(datetime.now().timestamp())) # Бесполезная строка

headers = {
    "user-agent": user_agent,
    "accept": '*/*'
}


def save_data():
    with open('parse_info.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(f'{title}\n')


def get_html(URL, params=None):
    r = requests.get(URL, headers=headers, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html): # Получаем контент
    for i in range(1, 5): # На месте 5 будет предположительное количество страниц указ. пользователем
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        items = soup.find_all('a', class_='market_listing_row_link')
        weapons = []
        for item in items: # Ищем нужные элементы
            weapons.append({
                'title': item.find('span', class_='market_listing_item_name').get_text(strip=True),
                'price': item.find('span', class_='sale_price').get_text(strip=True).replace('$', '').replace('USD', '').replace(' ', ''),
            })

        print(weapons)

        global weapon 
        global original_price
        global title
        for weapon in weapons: # Получаем нужные ключи. И записываем в ТХТ
            title = weapon['title']
            price = weapon['price']
            original_price = float(price)
            if 0.2 < original_price < 15:
                print(f'{title} -> {original_price}')
                save_data()
            #print(weapon['title']) 


def parse():
    html = get_html()
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print("error")

parse()
```

Вопрос:
Как реализовать пaгинацию через `URL` с шагом `count+=10` каждый раз после цикла `for` и повторный парсинг?

Comment: Не понятно, надо в параметре страницы значение 'page='+str(count) увеличивать или 'count' в конце? Или и то и то?

Comment: @Georgiy сейчас я постараюсь более точно сформулировать вопрос.
URL = 'https://example.com/page=0&count=10' - это начальная страница, а точнее первая. Мне нужно чтоб произошел парсинг этой страницы циклом for и page=0 выросло до page=10. Теперь URL = 'https://example.com/page=10&count=10' должен парситься и записаться в тхт и т.д. До 10000 страницы (как пример)
UPD. Я понял свою ошибку в вопросе. Я указал в примере URL count, на который заканчивается URL, который мне не нужен. Прошу прошения. Исправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методе range можно указать шаг итерации, нужно указать начало, конец и шаг:

```
for i in range(0, 11, 5):
    print(i)
... 
0
5
10
```

А на практике примерно будет так выглядеть парсер:

```
def get_html(page_count):
    url = 'https://example.com/page=' + str(page_count) + '&count=10'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return r


def parse():
    page_start, page_end = 0, 100
    for i in range(page_start, page_end, 10):
        html = get_html(i)
        if html.status_code == 200:
            get_content(html.text)
        #...
```

Или можно обернуть функцию получения страниц в генератор и по нему итерировать, сэкономив немного строк кода:

```
def get_html(page_start, page_end, step=10):
    for page in range(page_start, page_end, step):
        url = 'https://example.com/page=' + str(page) + '&count=10'
        yield requests.get(url, headers=headers)


def parse():
    page_start,page_end = 0, 100
    for html in get_html(page_start, page_end):
        if html.status_code == 200:
            get_content(html.text)
        #...
```